# Problems after upgrading to 14.04 from 12.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, upgrade

I have recently tried to upgrade my Ubuntu from 12.04 to 14.04 LTS. During the upgrade, no errors or warnings appeared.
When I start up, a screen appears saying
"Error - Diskfilter writes are not supported"

It boots up normally, showing the login screen, however, logging in to any account (I have two on the machine) just leads to a blank screen - I get the background of the login screen, can move the mouse, but nothing else happens.

As I am fairly new to Linux, I really do not know how to fix this. Will I have to downgrade again to 12.04?